# What is the best project structure for a Python application?

Tags: python, directory-structure, organization, project-structure

Imagine that you want to develop a non-trivial end-user desktop (not web) application in Python. What is the best way to structure the project's folder hierarchy?

Desirable features are ease of maintenance, IDE-friendliness, suitability for source control branching/merging, and easy generation of install packages.

In particular:

1. Where do you put the source?
2. Where do you put application startup scripts?
3. Where do you put the IDE project cruft?
4. Where do you put the unit/acceptance tests?
5. Where do you put non-Python data such as config files?
6. Where do you put non-Python sources such as C++ for pyd/so binary extension modules?

Comment: Can any of those SO individuals that keep voting for "question is not focused enough" please step up and propose a more "focused" question?

Comment: Something doesn't add up here. The question was tagged as "unfocused", but has clearly too many upvotes and views.

Answer (score 509, accepted):

Doesn't too much matter.  Whatever makes you happy will work.  There aren't a lot of silly rules because Python projects can be simple.

- `/scripts` or `/bin` for that kind of command-line interface stuff
- `/tests` for your tests
- `/lib` for your C-language libraries
- `/doc` for most documentation
- `/apidoc` for the Epydoc-generated API docs.

And the top-level directory can contain README's, Config's and whatnot.

The hard choice is whether or not to use a `/src` tree.  Python doesn't have a distinction between `/src`, `/lib`, and `/bin` like Java or C has.

Since a top-level `/src` directory is seen by some as meaningless, your top-level directory can be the top-level architecture of your application.

- `/foo`
- `/bar`
- `/baz`

I recommend putting all of this under the "name-of-my-product" directory.  So, if you're writing an application named `quux`, the directory that contains all this stuff is named  `/quux`.

Another project's `PYTHONPATH`, then, can include `/path/to/quux/foo` to reuse the `QUUX.foo` module.

In my case, since I use Komodo Edit, my IDE cuft is a single .KPF file.  I actually put that in the top-level `/quux` directory, and omit adding it to SVN.

Comment: Any open source python projects you would recommend emulating their directory structure?

Comment: Look at Django for a good example.

Comment: I don't tend to consider Django a good example -- playing tricks with sys.path is an instant DQ in my book.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: "tricks with sys.path"?  Can you provide a link or quote?

Comment: I am an advocate of the src directory.

Comment: re "tricks": Django adds the parent of the root project folder to the sys.path, so that modules can be imported as either "from project.app.module import klass" or "from app.module import klass".

Comment: Oh, I love this trick and am using it now. I want to put the shared module in another directory, and I do not want to install module system-wide, nor do I want to ask people to modify PYTHONPATH manually. Unless people propose something better, I think this is actually the cleanest way to go.

Comment: I recently create a tool can help you initiate a python project from scratch.  by typing some info like: package_name, github_username, license, python version you want to support. And having virtualenv, test, code coverage, doc, deploy doc, publish to pypi, multi python version test (tox) out of the box! And it compatible with WINDOWS / MACOS / LINUX. Check this out: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygitrepo

Comment: cuft -> cruft* .

Comment: Re Django's tricks, I believe they removed that as of version 1.4.  (See [this discussion](http://ncoghlan-devs-python-notes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap).)

Comment: "`/scripts` or `/bin`": I would not do that. You can define `entry_points` in setup.py and have a `cli.py` or something similar with that as part of the package.

Comment: Using `src` is better because it's a predictable conventional name, @khatchad, and you can use that in your tooling and deploy templates. Also naming after the project is not always so simple and can lead to bad choices.

Comment: Top level `src` is by no means meaningless. It separates out the code that will eventually be in production from all the tests and project control. If your source is not a package (e.g. AWS Lambda) it's essential, and even if your source is a package or packages it keeps it clean to separate off all the code at the top level.

Answer (score 319):

According to Jean-Paul Calderone's [Filesystem structure of a Python project](http://as.ynchrono.us/2007/12/filesystem-structure-of-python-project_21.html):

```
Project/
|-- bin/
|   |-- project
|
|-- project/
|   |-- test/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- test_main.py
|   |   
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- main.py
|
|-- setup.py
|-- README
```

Comment: After blithely ignoring this I eventually had to shuffle my stuff to look like this in order to make it easy to make rpms out of. Highly recommend everyone use this setup by default unless you have a really good reason not to.

Comment: how does executable file in the bin folder reference the project module? (I don't think python syntax allows `../` in an include statement)

Comment: @ThorSummoner That is actually a very good question to me, appart from tweaking the PYTHON_PATH I do not see how to do it. It seems to me that this structure makes running the project startup script unnecessarily complicated (putting the 'project' file directly under project/ removes the need to tweak PYTHON_PATH).

Comment: Actually, Python does support going up directories; See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1054281/1695680.

Comment: @ThorSummoner That only works when remaining inside a single package. For the relative import to work here you'd need an `__init__.py` file in both the `bin` folder and the `Project` top folder.

Comment: @ThorSummoner Simple. You install the package! (`pip install -e /path/to/Project`)

Comment: It would be awesome if someone would zip up a sample of this layout with hello.py and hello-test.py and make it available for us newbs.

Comment: having folder `/bin` with executables sounds like a very bad practice to me: you have problems with importing as mentioned above and have to fiddle with `PYTHONPATH`; I prefer using [entry_points](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation)

Comment: What is the naming convention for project Directory for python PascalCase or this-case?

Comment: @Kroltan Could you please explain what happens after `pip install`ing the package that allows you to nicely run an executable file from the `bin` folder which nicely references the project module?

Comment: @Bloke The core is the `-e` flag, which installs the package as an editable package, that is, installs it as links to the actual project folder. The executable can then just `import project` to have access to the module.

Comment: This thread is quite old, but I can shed some light on the matter of putting the executable `project` in `bin`. Apparently it's relevant to Linux systems where the executable is meant to usually be a shell script (with the same name as your Python *project*). More info [here](https://coderwall.com/p/lt2kew/python-creating-your-project-structure "Python: Creating Your Project Structure").

Comment: This post seems rather outdated, I have not found a single project that uses this structure. Could you point me to some? Or maybe add a header in the answer saying it is old?

Comment: The link to http://as.ynchrono.us/2007/12/filesystem-structure-of-python-project_21.html is dead.

Comment: The proposed structure is outdated and not recommended today. Please see https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: @trk One reason to do this (not Linux specific) is because in many software projects you have a similar thing. For example in compiled languages such as C/C++/Rust etc. You have a bunch of binaries (more than one) which all in general rely on some supporting code which is part of a library which is "locally shared" within the same "project". This is just to replicate that structure in Python, which is a sensible approach. Otherwise you end up with a single folder containing all your exeutable "binraries" (scripts) along with all the supporting library code;

Comment: For more information see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77507389/python-project-directory-structure-modulenotfounderror

Answer (score 304):

This [blog post by Jean-Paul Calderone](https://jcalderone.livejournal.com/39794.html) is commonly given as an answer in #python on Freenode.

> ### Filesystem structure of a Python project
>
> Do:
>
> - name the directory something related to your project. For example, if your project is named "Twisted", name the top-level directory for its source files `Twisted`. When you do releases, you should include a version number suffix: `Twisted-2.5`.
> - create a directory `Twisted/bin` and put your executables there, if you have any. Don't give them a `.py` extension, even if they are Python source files. Don't put any code in them except an import of and call to a main function defined somewhere else in your projects. (Slight wrinkle: since on Windows, the interpreter is selected by the file extension, your Windows users actually do want the .py extension. So, when you package for Windows, you may want to add it. Unfortunately there's no easy distutils trick that I know of to automate this process. Considering that on POSIX the .py extension is a only a wart, whereas on Windows the lack is an actual bug, if your userbase includes Windows users, you may want to opt to just have the .py extension everywhere.)
> - If your project is expressable as a single Python source file, then put it into the directory and name it something related to your project. For example, `Twisted/twisted.py`. If you need multiple source files, create a package instead (`Twisted/twisted/`, with an empty `Twisted/twisted/__init__.py`) and place your source files in it. For example, `Twisted/twisted/internet.py`.
> - put your unit tests in a sub-package of your package (note - this means that the single Python source file option above was a trick - you **always** need at least one other file for your unit tests). For example, `Twisted/twisted/test/`. Of course, make it a package with `Twisted/twisted/test/__init__.py`. Place tests in files like `Twisted/twisted/test/test_internet.py`.
> - add `Twisted/README` and `Twisted/setup.py` to explain and install your software, respectively, if you're feeling nice.
>
> Don't:
>
> - put your source in a directory called `src` or `lib`. This makes it hard to run without installing.
> - put your tests outside of your Python package. This makes it hard to run the tests against an installed version.
> - create a package that **only** has a `__init__.py` and then put all your code into `__init__.py`. Just make a module instead of a package, it's simpler.
> - try to come up with magical hacks to make Python able to import your module or package without having the user add the directory containing it to their import path (either via PYTHONPATH or some other mechanism). You will **not** correctly handle all cases and users will get angry at you when your software doesn't work in their environment.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. "DONT try to come up with magical hacks to make Python able to import your module or package without having the user add the directory containing it to their import path." Good to know!

Comment: Thing is, this does not mention the important doc part of a project where to place it.

Comment: Confused about "put your source in a directory called src or lib. This makes it hard to run without installing.".  What would be installed? Is it the dir name that causes the issue, or the fact that it is a subdir at all?

Comment: "Some people will assert that you should distribute your tests within your module itself – I disagree. It often increases complexity for your users; many test suites often require additional dependencies and runtime contexts." https://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing/structure/#test-suite

Comment: @JackO'Connor I am confused. How do you do an import to the main function defined inside `Twisted/twisted` from the executable in `Twisted/bin` without modifying paths?

Comment: @GoodDeeds I think the standard way is to have the user install the library, either globally or in some virtualenv that they're using, so that the import works. I do sometimes like to include a bash script that sets the necessary PYTHONPATH and executes the code locally, to help with development, but I'm not sure what other people do.

Comment: "This makes it hard to run without installing." -- that's the *point*

Comment: I find it ironical that the example uses `Twisted` as the project name, since the official [`Twisted` library](https://github.com/twisted/twisted) now uses a `src` layout, which contradicts the first "Don't" recommendation: "put your source in a directory called src or lib. This makes it hard to run without installing." This is the whole point (see [Ionel Cristian Mărieș's article](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/)).

Comment: Do: "put your source in a directory called src or lib."

Comment: Actually "This makes it hard to run without installing." is a huge advantage. Everyone should be installing with `pip install -e`, then there's no ambiguity and chance of testing not what you think you're testing

Comment: The "don't" section sounds extremely pythonic, however, like many (lazy) Python community practices, are prone to mistakes and incidental complexty - as some commenters pointed out as well.

Comment: The link provided to the blog post is broken, [here it is](https://web.archive.org/web/20210410230221/https://as.ynchrono.us/2007/12/filesystem-structure-of-python-project_21.html) on the WayBackMachine with comments

Comment: The link is not available

Comment: Does this advice still stand? It's 15 years old and Python packaging went a very long way since then. To me some points look outdated and counterproducive.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov See https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Answer (score 157):

Check out [Open Sourcing a Python Project the Right Way](https://web.archive.org/web/20201214181824/https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/).

Let me excerpt the *project layout* part of that excellent article:

> When setting up a project, the layout (or directory structure) is important to get right. A sensible layout means that potential contributors don't have to spend forever hunting for a piece of code; file locations are intuitive. Since we're dealing with an existing project, it means you'll probably need to move some stuff around.
>
> Let's start at the top. Most projects have a number of top-level files (like setup.py, README.md, requirements.txt, etc). There are then three directories that every project should have:
>
> - A docs directory containing project documentation
> - A directory named with the project's name which stores the actual Python package
> - A test directory in one of two places
>
>   - Under the package directory containing test code and resources
>   - As a stand-alone top level directory
>     To get a better sense of how your files should be organized, here's a simplified snapshot of the layout for one of my projects, sandman:
>
> ```
> $ pwd
> ~/code/sandman
> $ tree
> .
> |- LICENSE
> |- README.md
> |- TODO.md
> |- docs
> |   |-- conf.py
> |   |-- generated
> |   |-- index.rst
> |   |-- installation.rst
> |   |-- modules.rst
> |   |-- quickstart.rst
> |   |-- sandman.rst
> |- requirements.txt
> |- sandman
> |   |-- __init__.py
> |   |-- exception.py
> |   |-- model.py
> |   |-- sandman.py
> |   |-- test
> |       |-- models.py
> |       |-- test_sandman.py
> |- setup.py
> ```
>
> As you can see, there are some top level files, a docs directory (generated is an empty directory where sphinx will put the generated documentation), a sandman directory, and a test directory under sandman.

Comment: I do this, but more so: I have a toplevel Makefile with an 'env' target that automates 'virtualenv env ; ./env/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt ; ./env/bin/python setup.py develop', and also usually a 'test' target that depends on env and also installs test dependencies and then runs py.test.

Comment: @pjz Could you please expand your idea? Are you talking about putting `Makefile` at the same level as `setup.py`? So if I understands you correctly `make env` automates creatating a new `venv` and install the packages into it... ?

Comment: @St.Antario exactly.  As mentioned I generally also have a 'test' target to run the tests, and sometimes a 'release' target that looks at the current tag and builds a wheel and sends it to pypi.

Comment: In this structure, how does any file inside `/code/sandman/sandman/` import something in `/code/sandman/docs/`? Say, I want to import `config.py` from `sandman.py`. How should I do that?

Comment: This answer is outdated and not recommended anymore. Please don't reproduce this today. See https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Answer (score 56):

The "Python Packaging Authority" has a sampleproject:

https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject

It is a sample project that exists as an aid to the Python Packaging User Guide's Tutorial on Packaging and Distributing Projects.

Comment: + trend towards `root/src/*` structure: https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/commit/56d3120cc2a1727c00aad9418e6612abbbd55830

Comment: for project structure recs also see https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/

Answer (score 32):

Try starting the project using the [python_boilerplate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python_boilerplate_template) template. It largely follows the best practices (e.g. [those here](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/)), but is better suited in case you find yourself willing to split your project into more than one egg at some point (and believe me, with anything but the simplest projects, you will. One common situation is where you have to use a locally-modified version of someone else's library).

- **Where do you put the source?**

  - For decently large projects it makes sense to split the source into several eggs. Each egg would go as a separate setuptools-layout under `PROJECT_ROOT/src/<egg_name>`.
- **Where do you put application startup scripts?**

  - The ideal option is to have application startup script registered as an `entry_point` in one of the eggs.
- **Where do you put the IDE project cruft?**

  - Depends on the IDE. Many of them keep their stuff in `PROJECT_ROOT/.<something>` in the root of the project, and this is fine.
- **Where do you put the unit/acceptance tests?**

  - Each egg has a separate set of tests, kept in its `PROJECT_ROOT/src/<egg_name>/tests` directory. I personally prefer to use `py.test` to run them.
- **Where do you put non-Python data such as config files?**

  - It depends. There can be different types of non-Python data.

    - *"Resources"*, i.e. data that must be packaged within an egg. This data goes into the corresponding egg directory, somewhere within package namespace. It can be used via the `pkg_resources` package from `setuptools`, or since Python 3.7 via the `importlib.resources` module from the standard library.
    - *"Config-files"*, i.e. non-Python files that are to be regarded as external to the project source files, but have to be initialized with some values when application starts running. During development I prefer to keep such files in `PROJECT_ROOT/config`. For deployment there can be various options. On Windows one can use `%APP_DATA%/<app-name>/config`, on Linux, `/etc/<app-name>` or `/opt/<app-name>/config`.
    - *Generated files*, i.e. files that may be created or modified by the application during execution. I would prefer to keep them in `PROJECT_ROOT/var` during development, and under `/var` during Linux deployment.
- **Where do you put non-Python sources such as C++ for pyd/so binary extension modules?**

  - Into `PROJECT_ROOT/src/<egg_name>/native`

Documentation would typically go into `PROJECT_ROOT/doc` or `PROJECT_ROOT/src/<egg_name>/doc` (this depends on whether you regard some of the eggs to be a separate large projects). Some additional configuration will be in files like `PROJECT_ROOT/buildout.cfg` and `PROJECT_ROOT/setup.cfg`.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! You clarified many things for me!
I just have one question: Can eggs be nested?

Comment: No, you can't "nest" eggs in the sense of storing .egg files within other .egg files and hoping this would be of much use [unless you're up to something really weird].

What you can do, though, is create "virtual" eggs - empty packages that do not provide any useful code, but list other packages in their dependency lists. This way, when a user attempts to install such a package he will recursively install many dependent eggs.

Comment: @KT can you elaborate a bit about how you handle generated data? In particular, how do you (in code) distinguish between development and deployment? I imagine you have some `base_data_location` variable, but how do you set it appropriately?

Comment: I presume you are speaking about "runtime data" - something people would often put under /var/packagename or ~/.packagename/var, or whatnot. Most of the time those choices are sufficient as a default that your users don't care to change.
If you want to allow this behaviour to be tuned, options are rather abundant and I do not think there is a single fits-all best practice. Typical choices: a) ~/.packagename/configfile, b) export MY_PACKAGE_CONFIG=/path/to/configfile c) command-line options or function parameters d) combination of those.

Comment: Note that it is quite usual to have a singleton Config class somewhere, which handles your favourite config loading logic for you and perhaps even lets the user modify the settings at runtime.

In general, though, I think this is an issue worth a separate question (which might have been asked before somewhere here).

Comment: What a great answer, especially the part about non-Python data, thanks!

Comment: Is the `python_boilerplate_template` still a valid solution in 2021? How long can such solution be still valid. Probably my question is a little vague, but still interesting to know for those like me, who are just students or junior developers. Also, I'm a little worried that the las update that repo had was around 2014 (around 7 years ago at the time of writing).

Comment: @carloswm85 It is for sure still a valid solution, however not without its flair of "old-schoolness", as Buildout has considerably lost in popularity (together with Django, its most famous adopter). Pipenv has been a widely popularized tool to fill the same niche, but its adoption also seems to vane nowadays - many projects resort to manually managing barebones virtualenv + requirements.txt files. It is not that complicated after all, and both Pipenv and Buildout are quite thin opinionated wrappers around this workflow. Project.toml is another "modern" thing that is missing from the template.

Answer (score 20):

In my experience, it's just a matter of iteration.  Put your data and code wherever you think they go.  Chances are, you'll be wrong anyway.  But once you get a better idea of exactly how things are going to shape up, you're in a much better position to make these kinds of guesses.

As far as extension sources, we have a Code directory under trunk that contains a directory for python and a directory for various other languages.  Personally, I'm more inclined to try putting any extension code into its own repository next time around.

With that said, I go back to my initial point:  don't make too big a deal out of it.  Put it somewhere that seems to work for you.  If you find something that doesn't work, it can (and should) be changed.

Comment: Yep. I try to be "Pythonic" about it: explicit is better than implicit.. Directory heirarchies are read/inspected more than they are written. Etc..

Answer (score 15):

Non-python data is best bundled inside your Python modules using the `package_data` support in [setuptools](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools). One thing I strongly recommend is using namespace packages to create shared namespaces which multiple projects can use -- much like the Java convention of putting packages in `com.yourcompany.yourproject` (and being able to have a shared `com.yourcompany.utils` namespace).

Re branching and merging, if you use a good enough source control system it will handle merges even through renames; [Bazaar](http://www.bazaar-vcs.org/) is particularly good at this.

Contrary to some other answers here, I'm +1 on having a `src` directory top-level (with `doc` and `test` directories alongside). Specific conventions for documentation directory trees will vary depending on what you're using; [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/), for instance, has its own conventions which its quickstart tool supports.

Please, please leverage setuptools and pkg_resources; this makes it much easier for other projects to rely on specific versions of your code (and for multiple versions to be simultaneously installed with different non-code files, if you're using `package_data`).