# Import a class from a folder at another level

Tags: python, import

I have a python application like this

```
/
/crawl.py
/crawl/__init__.py
/crawl/john.py
/tests/test_john.py
```

What I am trying to do, is run the unit test `test_john.py` which needs to use `john.py` but it's in another folder.

In my `tests/test_john.py` I get this when I run it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_john.py", line 2, in <module>
    from john import John
ImportError: No module named john
```

So how can I import a class, from the crawl folder....

Comment: you could try `from crawl.john import John` or try `from ..crawl.john import John` (refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054271/how-to-import-a-python-class-that-is-in-a-directory-above)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your root folder is in your pythonpath and you make it an importable package as follows:

```
/__init__.py
/crawl.py
/crawl/__init__.py
/crawl/john.py
/tests/__init__.py
/tests/test_john.py
```

you can do:

```
from crawl.john import John
```

or

```
from ..crawl.john import John
```

Comment: Seems the root folder is not in my python path. I thought it might add the CWD to the pythonpath but doesn't. Best way to do it?

Comment: that depends on your configuration. In windows, for my packages and libraries I simply add a site.pth file in site-packages with the name of the folder(s).

Answer (score 3):

If your OS supports it, put a symbolic link to `../crawl` in the `test` directory and then use `from crawl.john import John`.