# Python -- import a module from a directory that's not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a directory structure like this...

```
dir/
  build.py
dir2
  dir3/
  packages.py
```

Now the `build.py` needs `packages.py` -- and note that `dir2` is not a package.

So what's the best way to get `packages.py` loaded into `build.py` (the directory structure can't be changed)

**EDIT**

The `sys.path.append` solution seems good -- but there is one thing -- I need to use the `packages.py` file rarely -- and keeping a `sys.path` that includes a directory that is used rarely, but is at the front -- is that the best thing?

**EDIT II**

I think the `imp` solution is best.

```
import imp    
packages = imp.load_source('packages', '/path/to/packages.py')
```

**EDIT III**

### for Python 3.x

Note that `imp.load_source` and some other function [have been deprecated](http://bugs.python.org/issue14551). So you should use the `imp.load_module` today.

```
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('packages', '/path/to/packages.py')
try:
    mod = imp.load_module('packages', fp, pathname, description)
finally:
    # since we may exit via an exception, close fp explicitly
    if fp:
        fp.close()
```

Comment: The best option here is to make it a package. Can you **really** not do that?

Comment: NO I can't. Because inside `dir2`, other than `packages.py` -- all others are non-python files. The `packages.py` just contains some config info for the `build.py`

Comment: Have you considered using a different format for the configuration file? If your configuration doesn't require code in it, why not store the configuration as `JSON` or some other similar format? That way you don't need to import it. Also, you can have other files in a Python package, I don't really see why that is an issue.

Comment: About other formats -- I think in my case python file for config is more suitable and flexible than anything else.

Comment: @good_computer, find_module and load_module is deprecated too and so will the whole imp module in the future, maybe you should replace it with an example using importlib if possible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do:

```
sys.path.append('./dir2/dir3')
import packages
```

Or better yet:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'dir2/dir3'))
import packages
```

Or (taken from here: [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path))

```
import imp    
packages = imp.load_source('packages', '/path/to/packages.py')
```

Comment: Would the 'one right way' to do be the third ? - avoids messing directly with `sys.path`

Answer (score 6):

Would the 'one right way' to do be the third ? - avoids messing directly with `sys.path`

I meet the same problems, and I solve it.

```
dir/
  build.py
dir2
  dir3/
    packages.py
```

1. **add the file `__init__.py`** into the `dir1, dir2, dir3 ...`
2. Inside a package hierarchy, **use two dots**.

---

`bulid.py` want to import `packages.py`, write in bulid.py:

```
import ..dir2.dir3.packages
from ..dir2.dir3.packages import function
```

> https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328-absolute-and-relative-imports
>
> [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)
>
> [How to import a Python class that is in a directory above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054271/how-to-import-a-python-class-that-is-in-a-directory-above)