# SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd1' in file modules/commands.pyc

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

I have a python file, `[working dir/]modules/commands.py`, which contains only the following:

```
def getId():
    return "commands"
```

Then I have another file, `[working dir/]main.py`, which uses the following:

```
fpath = "modules/commands.py"
mname = "commands"
imp.load_source(mname, fpath)
```

After I added the `getId()` to `commands.py` I started getting the following error when trying to run `main.py`:

`SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd1' in file modules/commands.pyc on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details`

The error complains about non-ascii characters, but there should be none in the file. What is causing the error?

Edit:
The problem goes away temporarily if I remove the .pyc file, but comes back next time.

Comment: help(imp) says "undocumented functions are obsolete" and `load_source` is undocumented.  Is there some reason not to use the documented `load_module` function?  Based on the error it seems like `load_source` is loading the compiled (`.pyc`) file as if it were source code, but since it's not documented, that's all just a guess.

Comment: working fine for me ! may be try removing `[working dir/]modules/__pycache__`

Comment: @torek The only reason I use that is that it is the first one I found a nice example of with google. I might look into load_module

Comment: @rnbcoder I can not find such a file/directory

Comment: hum. better to use `load_module` then.

Comment: @rnbcoder Wanna turn that into an answer?

Comment: As an interesting fact load_source seems to be somewhat popular. A google for "load_module example" brings this as promising link as the second: [How to import a module given the full path? (stackoverflow)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path). Multiple answers with load_source have literally got 100x more upvotes than the single one that mentions load_module

Comment: Related, mentions deprecation of load_source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533679/python-import-a-module-from-a-directory-thats-not-a-package

Comment: Use hexedit to check the code is really what you think it is. Some editors, may, sometime, insert nonprintable characters which you don't see but they break stuff.

Comment: @varesa I don't know much about imp module. Look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/282778/1682673).

Answer (score 3):

(As nobody seemed to want the rep, I'll write an answer myself)

The method `load_source()` from the `imp`-module has been marked obsolete, and even removed completely from the documentation of python 3.X.

The solution was to use `find_module()` and `load_module()` from the same `imp`-module instead. After changing to them it started working flawlessly.

The obsolete functions seem to be somewhat buggy in that behavior (atleast in python 2.6.6 on Centos 6)