# python module imports issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

here's a picture of my directory structure:

```
parts.py
machine/
    __init__.py
    parts.py
```

I have a directory (a package) called machine

in it there is __init__.py and parts.py

at the same level as machine, there is a file named parts.py

in parts.py, the code looks like this:

```
#parts.py
class Parts(object):
    pass
```

in machine.parts the code looks like this

```
 #machine.parts
 from parts import Parts
 class MachineParts(Parts):
     pass
```

When I try to import machine.parts, I get an import error. I don't want to change my directory structure. How should I fix this and retain good PEP8 style?

Comment: in machine.parts what do you mean by `from Parts import Parts`

Comment: thanks! I corrected the typo

Comment: You should make it all a package (by adding `__init__.py` near `parts.py`) and use absolute imports, like `from mypackage.parts import Parts`.

Comment: this is good! can you write this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make it a package by adding top-level `__init__.py` and giving some meaningful name to top-level directory:

```
mypackage
    __init__.py
    parts.py
    machine/
        __init__.py
        parts.py
```

Then, use absolute imports:

```
#machine.parts
from mypackage.parts import Parts
class MachineParts(Parts):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `import` supports relative imports, try:

```
from ..parts import Parts
```

Another option is to use an absolute import:

```
from appname.parts import Parts
```

As mentioned in [How to import a Python class that is in a directory above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054271/how-to-import-a-python-class-that-is-in-a-directory-above/1054281#1054281)

Comment: relative imports are considered bad style

Comment: but it is part of PEP328 - how is that bad style? Naming files the same name might be considered bad style as well... confusing for your fellow developer (conside `parent_parts.py`?)

Comment: fair enough, I only read not to use relative imports in the google styleguide. Relative imports don't work here though

Comment: use an absolute import (although frowned upon as well)