# Python 2.7.9: Unable to import from module

Tags: python, importerror

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
Project
|+-- test.py
|
+>> agents
|  +-- __init__.py
|  +-- TestAgent.py
|    
+>> automation
|  +-- __init__.py
|  |
|  +>> navigators
|      +--__init__.py
|      +--SystemNavigator.py
```

Inside _ _ init _ _.py under agents I have the following code:

```
from TestAgent import TestAgent
```

And inside SystemNavigator I have:

```
from agents import TestAgent
```

When I attempt to run the program, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
from navigators import SystemNavigator
File "/Users/jb/Desktop/code/tools/pythontest/automation/navigators/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from SystemNavigator import SystemNavigator
File "/Users/jb/Desktop/code/tools/pythontest/automation/navigators/SystemNavigator.py", line 1, in <module>
from agents import TestAgent
ImportError: No module named agents
```

I setup an identical file structure in a separate directory to double check, and I was able to get this working there. I read around Stack Overflow and elsewhere. I'd like to avoid any changes to sys.path or changes to my directory structure. Based on others suggestions, I tried deleting .pyc files within the directory and also deleting / recreating the _ _ init _ _.py under agents.

Does anyone have advice on where I should look next to troubleshoot? I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Is the `Project` directory on your `sys.path`?  If not, you will not be able to import from packages inside it.

Comment: I would recommend the use of lowercase filenames. Having __init__.py import TestAgent from TestAgent means that TestAgent has a somewhat ambiguous name.

Comment: see [how-to-import-a-python-class-that-is-in-a-directory-above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054271/how-to-import-a-python-class-that-is-in-a-directory-above)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on this. Adding the directory to the sys.path and the directions on how to import a python class from a directory above are both good options. I appreciate it!