# I am trying to import a models.py method, but get error no module named

Tags: python, django

I have 2 apps:

> friends/apps/loginreg/models.py/User
>   friends/apps/friends/views.py

I am trying to import the User method into the `views.py` file.

These are my imports:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from .models import Friend
from loginreg.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
```

It continues to give `error` no module named `loginreg.models`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'from' path is wrong, I think.
Try `from ..loginreg.models import User`

You're trying to import from a folder above your current one. You can [read more about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054271/how-to-import-a-python-class-that-is-in-a-directory-above).

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/folder')

import file
```

Python searches the current folder for the modules. This way you can add the path to search your module at runtime

Or you could normally import it the way you are, but in that case you need to make sure that there is a file `__init__.py` inside the parent folder of your module file. This would allow it to be included as a package. That `__init__.py` file could be empty. It is just there to tell Python to treat the folder as a package.

[More details here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)