# ModuleNotFoundError when running script from Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have the following folder structure:

- `app`

  - `__init__.py`
  - `utils`

    - `__init__.py`
    - `transform.py`
  - `products`

    - `__init__.py`
    - `fish.py`

In fish.py I'm importing `transform` as following: `import utils.transform`.

When I'm running fish.py from Pycharm, it works perfectly fine. However when I am running fish.py from the Terminal, I am getting error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`.

Command I use in Terminal: from app folder `python products/fish.py`.

I've already looked into the solutions suggested here: [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder), adding a path to the application folder into the `sys.path` helps. However I am wondering if there is any other way of making it work without adding two lines of code into the `fish.py`. It's because I have many scripts in the /products directory, and do not want to add 2 lines of code into each of them.

I looked into some open source projects, and I saw many examples of importing modules from a parallel folder without adding anything into sys.path, e.g. here:
https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie/blob/master/httpie/plugins/builtin.py#L5

How to make it work for my project in the same way?

Comment: Check if you are using a virtual environment in Pycharm by looking at the settings

Comment: @NicolòGasparini I think am using virtualnev in Pycharm: in Project Interpreter I selected /application/venv/bin/python. I am using the same virtualnev in Terminal too...

Comment: Can you show where your `__init__.py` files live?

Comment: Also show how you run your module from the command line. I'm guessing PyCharm is very smart about setting up your path.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054271/how-to-import-a-python-class-that-is-in-a-directory-above, it should do what you need, however in the long run if your utils folder grows you may want to ensure it is in the path so you do not have to do relative imports. You may encounter this though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have `__init__.py` inside utils and inside products

Comment: You don't want to put one in apps?

Comment: @MadPhysicist in Terminal from the application folder I run: `python products/fish.py`

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, I also have __init__.py inside the application folder.

Comment: You might also want to take a look ath his post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder?noredirect=1&lq=1 
There is a thorough guide about Python imports by Chris Yeh: https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html

Comment: Please update your question with the new information on the folder structure, and an example of how you attempted to run your module.

Comment: Did you mean to have an `__init__.py` file in the `app` folder? Is `app` a package (so that the subpackages are `app.utils` and `app.products`?

Comment: Dupe of [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You probably want to run `python -m products.fish`. The difference between that and `python products/fish.py` is that the former is roughly equivalent to doing `import products.fish` in the shell (but with `__name__` set to `__main__`), while the latter does not have awareness of its place in a package hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks Mad, I just tried running `python -m products.fish`, it works!

Comment: this fixed my problem

meanwhile, i don't understand it since it works on one machine running a fresh install of all dependencies in the same version of python's virtual environment, but not on another with  the same setup. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 23):

This expands on @Mad Physicist's answer.

---

First, assuming `app` is itself a package (since you added `__init__.py` to it) and `utils` and `products` are its subpackages, you should **change the import to `import app.utils.transform`**, and **run Python from the root directory** (the parent of `app`). The rest of this answer assumes you've done this. (If it wasn't your intention making `app` the root package, tell me in a comment.)

---

The problem is that you're running `app.products.fish` as if it were a script, i.e. by giving the full path of the file to the `python` command:

```sh
python app/products/fish.py
```

This makes Python think this `fish.py` file is a standalone script that isn't part of any package. As defined in the docs (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=command%20line), under `<script>`), this means that Python will search for modules in the same directory as the script, i.e. `app/products/`:

> If the script name refers directly to a Python file, the directory
> containing that file is added to the start of `sys.path`, and the file
> is executed as the `__main__` module.

But of course, the `app` folder is not in `app/products/`, so it will throw an error if you try to import `app` or any subpackage (e.g. `app.utils`).

The correct way to start a script that is part of a package is to use the **`-m` (module) switch** ([reference](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=command%20line#cmdoption-m)), which takes a module path as an argument and executes that module as a script (but keeping the current working directory as a module search path):

> If this option is given, [...] the current directory
> will be added to the start of `sys.path`.

So you should use the following to start your program:

```sh
python -m app.products.fish
```

Now when `app.products.fish` tries to import the `app.utils.transform` module, it will search for `app` in your current working directory (which contains the `app/...` tree) and succeed.

---

As a personal recommendation: *don't put runnable scripts inside packages*. Use packages only to store all the logic and functionality (functions, classes, constants, etc.) and write a separate script to run your application as you wish, putting it *outside* the package. This will save you from this kind of problems (including [the double import trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap)), and has also the advantage that you can write several run configurations for the same package by just making a separate startup script for each.