# File importing on python project

Tags: python

I want to have following project directory structure in python:

```
project\
    generic.py
    subdir1\
        file1.py
    subdir2\
        file2.py
    subdir3\
        file3.py
```

within file1.py I want to import *generic.py* from a root dir of project.

```
import generic
```

Unfortunatelly I got error when a try to execute "file1.py"

```
root:~/project/sidir1# python file1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file1.py", line 7, in <module>
    import generic
ImportError: No module named generic
```

I want to execute individual *file*.py* and have *generic.py* included.

How to correctly include it under such a drirectory structure?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your python project a package by making `__init__.py` in the root directory.

You can then use relative imports, ex: `from .. import generic`

Comment: I added /__init__.py and within my file1.py did "import ..generic" but still syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Have a Look here:
How to import a Python class that is in a directory above? [How to import a Python class that is in a directory above?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1054271/10634095)

Comment: using  `from .. import generic`  I got error _ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package_ by following the recommendation

Answer (score 0):

It's cause of **Python path**, when you use `import`, python will try to find in every directory in `sys.path` if module with name given exist, if he don't found, he raise.

For fix your problem, just add parent directory to your python path

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
```

Comment: at which directory should I need to reside when adding sys.path.append("..")?

Comment: your working dir is not important, it's relative to the directory of the file that is launched

Answer (score 0):

I would encourage you to instead wrap `generic.py` within a package along with the other submodules. Importing from root is usually a good recipe to later needing to debug imports that no longer work the way they should. Relative imports within a package can also become problematic.

Just build a structure like this:

```
project\
    my_package\
        generic.py
        __init__.py
        subdir1\
            file1.py
            __init__.py
        subdir2\
            file2.py
            __init__.py
        subdir3\
            file3.py
            __init__.py
```

And now in `file*.py` do: `from my_package import generic`

Now on the `project` level put a `main.py` or similar script where you use the functions that are available in my_package.