# cannot import package from one directory up

Tags: python, import

I can't seem to figure out how to fix the error below when trying to import a file from one directory up and it's making me crazy. Python 3.6.7.

Here's how `The Internet` says it should be done, one directory up:

```
from .. import app
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "module1.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .. import app
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Here's the dir structure (It should be noted that I'm calling the script `module1.py` from inside `package1`):

```
--- project/
    --- __init__.py
    --- app.py
    --- package1/
        --- __init__.py
        --- module1.py
```

Here's what I've tried to fix it:

**Method 1** (same error)

```
import sys

HERE = Path(__file__).parent
sys.path.append(str(HERE / '../'))
from .. import app
```

**Method 2** [(found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import), same error)

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
from .. import app
```

**Method 3** ( also [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import), same error)

```
import sys

sys.path.append('.')
from .. import app
```

Comment: try this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054271/how-to-import-a-python-class-that-is-in-a-directory-above

Comment: @âńōŋŷXmoůŜ all those solutions are in my question

Comment: Your right. Let me try it on my own and will update you. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `import ..app`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say "I'm calling the script module1.py from inside package1"? Are you importing module1 when the error happens, or are you trying to call module1 as a script (python doesn't want you to do this -- create a setup.py file and define a console_scripts entry_point instead).

Comment: @thebjorn I'm importing `app` from `module1.py`, and running `python module1.py` from inside the `package1` dir

Comment: Sorry, but Python doesn't really support that usage pattern and you'll end up with the kind of hacks you're using all over the place -- i.e. you can delete your `__init__.py` files because you're not using them (instead you have to manipulate the path for every import). What you should do instead, and for which Python has excellent support, is to create a setup.py script with a `console_scripts` declaration (cf. https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point), then you can use imports the normal way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working on my laptop so I hope it works on your side as well.

**module1.py**

```
import sys
from os import path

sys.path.append(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
from app import print_app


print_app()
```

**app.py:**

```
def print_app():
    print('success')
    return None
```

Result:

```
$python module1.py 

'success'
```

Comment: you're importing in the reverse direction and in different files, but I tried your solution (only corrected) and I'm still getting the error. I'm thinking I need to restructure my project such that the entry point allows for this kind of importing.

Answer (score 2):

A standard package structure for Python looks like this:

```
c:\srv\tmp> tree project
project
|-- project
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- app.py
|   `-- package1
|       |-- __init__.py
|       `-- module1.py
`-- setup.py
```

where the project-root `c:\srv\tmp\project` contains a `setup.py` file and a subdirectory that is also named `project` containing the source code.

The contents of `module1.py`:

```
from .. import app

def module1_fn():
    print("In module1, have imported app as:", app)
```

and the contents of `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='project',
    packages=['project'],    # where to find sources
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': """
            module1-fn = project.package1.module1:module1_fn
        """
    }
)
```

now the "magic" part, from the directory containing `setup.py` run (note the `.` at the end):

```
c:\srv\tmp\project> pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///C:/srv/tmp/project
Installing collected packages: project
  Running setup.py develop for project
Successfully installed project
```

And now, from any directory, you can run:

```
c:\srv\tmp\project> module1-fn
In module1, have imported app as: <module 'project.app' from 'c:\srv\tmp\project\project\app.pyc'>
```

ie. `module1-fn` can be called directly from the shell(!), and `from .. import app` works directly(!!)