# How to import external scripts in a Airflow DAG with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, airflow

I have the following structure:

[image]

And I try to import the script inside some files of the `inbound_layer` like so:

```py
import calc
```

However I get the following error message on Airflow web:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: if you are using pycharm and add the package in project dependency than you can import it so , else you have to add the desired package in path to run it.

Comment: Sounds like to need to add the package to your path. See [How to import a Python class that is in a directory above?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11096846/8150685) as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed insert the following script inside at the top of `ren.py` :

```py
import sys, os
from airflow.models import Variable

DAGBAGS_DIR = Variable.get('DAGBAGS_DIR')
sys.path.append(DAGBAGS_DIR + '/bi/inbound_layer/')
```

This way I make available the current folder packages.

Answer (score 4):

For airflow DAG, when you import your own module, you need make sure 2 things:

1. where is the module? You need to find where is the root path in you airflow folder. For example, in my dev box, the folders are:

   > ~/projects/data/airflow/teams/team_name/projects/default/dags/dag_names/dag_files.py

The root is airflow, so if I put my modules my_module in

> ~/projects/data/airflow/teams/team_name/common

Then I need to use

```
from teams.team_name.common import my_module
```

In your case, if the root is the upper folder of *bi*, and you put the scripts of calc in `bi/inbound_layer/test.py` then you can use:

```
from bi.inbound_layer.test import calc
```

2. And you must make sure you have `\__init\__.py` files in the directory structure for the imports to function properly. You should have an empty file `\__init\__.py` in each folder in the path. It indicates this directory is part of airflow packages. In your case, you can use `touch \__init\__.py` (cli) under *bi* and _inbound_layer_ folders to create the empty `__init\__.py`.

Comment: What do you mean about the root path? is that the path where my dags are loaded?

Comment: Here, the path root I mentioned is the path defined in $PYTHONPATH. You can use "echo $PYTHONPATH" in you env to get it. BTW please vote on the answer.

Comment: Or, you can simply just add "bi" into your sys path.

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna post my specific solution, you tips really helped me!

Answer (score 4):

Airflow adds `dags/, plugins/, and config/` directories in the Airflow home to `PYTHONPATH` by default so you can for example create folder `commons` under `dags` folder, create file there (`scriptFileName` ). Assuming that script has some class (`GetJobDoneClass`) you want to import in your  `DAG` you can do it like this:

```
from common.scriptFileName import GetJobDoneClass
```

Comment: That's work. What happen if we don't want to have it under dags? and just another folder next to dags. How does it work?