# ImportError: No module named functions

Tags: python-3.x, module, importerror

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEEvY.png)

I don't know what am I doing wrong here. I am importing the module from the `functions` package in the `tests` package. I tried every method but couldn't solve this problem while I tried to run `valid_test.py`

Comment: We need a lot more info! We need to know where the functions package is located, we need to know how you are importing it in the valid_test.py. In other words we need to see your code and the folder structure containing the two packages

Comment: I have attached an image.

Comment: Is readmessages in the same directory as valid_test?

Comment: No, it's not. It's in the functions package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one dot before the *functions* so the python will know it is in the folder "above" the current location ([import statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement)).

This look like this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054271/how-to-import-a-python-class-that-is-in-a-directory-above).

> When specifying what module to import you do not have to specify the
>   absolute name of the module. When a module or package is contained
>   within another package it is possible to make a relative import within
>   the same top package without having to mention the package name. By
>   using leading dots in the specified module or package after from you
>   can specify how high to traverse up the current package hierarchy
>   without specifying exact names. One leading dot means the current
>   package where the module making the import exists. Two dots means up
>   one package level. Three dots is up two levels, etc. So if you execute
>   from . import mod from a module in the pkg package then you will end
>   up importing pkg.mod. If you execute from ..subpkg2 import mod from
>   within pkg.subpkg1 you will import pkg.subpkg2.mod. The specification
>   for relative imports is contained within PEP 328.

There is another way to solve this issue by adding the "father" folder to the sys.path
by:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__, '..')))
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have been getting the same problem again and again while using SPYDER with anaconda.
I make my own function in other file and import those functions. The code was still not running giving me the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_functions".**

**I am sure you are selecting lines and executing only selected line only**\

> ***Solution to problem is here below***
>
> To execute your code as whole/line by line Follow the steps.
>
> 1. Change the working directory of spyder to the folder of current file as here  https://pasteboard.co/ee79y0dLqzu4.png .
> 2. select lines and execute or you can also execute the whole code.