# How to import function from python file from one folder above?

Tags: python

This is a follow up to "[How to import a Python class that is in a directory above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054271/how-to-import-a-python-class-that-is-in-a-directory-above/23103505#23103505)", which gives how to import a file from the parent directory:

```
from .. import module
```

I to get a specific function from a file in the directory above.

This is my attempt: There is a file in the higher directory called `topLevel.py` which has a function called `test_function`.

```
from .. import topLevel
from topLevel import test_function
```

This is the error message:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [beyond top level package error in relative import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669474/beyond-top-level-package-error-in-relative-import)

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys 
sys.path.insert(0, "./../" )
from topLevel import test_function

test_function()
```