# Scripts in python package

Tags: python, packaging, directory-structure, project-structure

I develop python application which I decided to turn into package to be installed by `easy_install` or `pip` later. I've used search to find several good sources about directory structure for python packages See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application/193181#193181) or [this post](http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/39794.html).

I created following structure (I've omitted several files in the list to make structure be more clear)

```
Project/
|-- bin/
|-- my_package/
|   |-- test/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- test_server.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- server.py
|   |-- util.py
|-- doc/
|   |-- index.rst
|-- README.txt
|-- LICENSE.txt
|-- setup.py
```

After that I created executable script `server-run`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from my_package import server
    
server.main()
```

which I placed into `bin` directory. If I install my package with `python setup.py install` or via `pip/easy_install` everything works fine, I can run `server-run` and my server starts to handle incoming requests.

But my question is how to test that `server-run` works in development environment (**without prior installation of `my_package`**)? Also I want to use this script to run latest server code for dev purposes.

Development happens in `Project` directory so I am getting `ImportError` if I run `./bin/server-run`

```
user@host:~/dev/Project/$ ./bin/server-run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/server-run", line 2, in <module>
    import my_package
ImportError: No module named my_package
```

Is it possible to modify `bin/server-run` script so it will work if I run it from another folder somewhere in the filesystem (not necessarily from `Project` dir)? Also note that I want to use (if it is possible to achieve) the same script to run server in production environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need relative imports. Try

```
from .. import mypackage
```

or

```
from ..mypackage import server
```

The documentation is here

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

These work on Python 2.5 or newer.

To do it only in the development version, try:

```
try:
    from my_package import server
except ImportError:
    from ..my_package import server
```

Comment: But if I use this code `server-run` will not work after package installation.

Comment: Updated with the way to try the normal version first.

Comment: Huh. I forgot about ImportException :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for testing Python code while in development as if it was released

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to configure the right Python path, so Python knows to look for `my_package` in the current directory.

On Linux (using Bash):

```
export PYTHONPATH=.
bin/server-run
```

On Windows:

```
set PYTHONPATH=.
python bin/server-run
```

Answer (score 2):

There is the [console_scripts approach](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html) now. See e.g.

```
entry_points={
      'console_scripts': [
        'wikibackup = wikibot.wikipush:mainBackup',   
        'wikiedit = wikibot.wikipush:mainEdit',
        'wikinuke = wikibot.wikipush:mainNuke',
        'wikipush = wikibot.wikipush:mainPush',
        'wikiupload = wikibot.wikipush:mainUpload',
        'wikiuser = wikibot.wikiuser:main',
      ],
    },
```

from https://pypi.org/project/py-3rdparty-mediawiki/ (where i am a committer).

If you do a pip install of that package the above scripts will be installed as part of the installation process.

see https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/py-3rdparty-mediawiki/blob/master/setup.py for the full source code of the setup script.