# Source code folder structure (bin, lib, src, config etc. ) for Java/Python applications

Tags: java

How do I decide the source code folder structure (bin, lib, src, config etc.) for Java applications? I mainly want to develop applications related to Data Mining and Information Retrieval. Are there sources or books where I can learn more about this?

Answer (score 7):

It won't be the same for Java and Python.

For Java, it depends on build automation tool you use. If you decide to use Maven, it will suggest you the source folder code sructure. See the [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). Ant uses another directory structure: [Building with Ant: Directory Structure](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/994991/Building-with-Ant-Directory-Structure.htm).

As for Python, see this question: [What is the best project structure for a Python application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application)

Comment: I cannot recommend this enough, for Java projects always use the standard Standard Directory Layout.