# Python -- import from modules the same directory

Tags: python, import, module, directory, yaml

I'm importing a python class stored on : pylearn2/datasets/ When I import other files on that directory says OK but when I try to import a file called make_dataset.py that I've just created says :

> Could not import pylearn2.datasets.make_dataset but could import
>   pylearn2.datasets. Original exception: No module named make_dataset

Here's the structure of the directory:

```
   pylearn2\
       __init__.py 
       datasets\
          __init__.py
          hepatitis.py
          matlab_dataset.py
          make_dataset.py
               ...
```

Could you explain me why I'm gettig that error?
I'm also using a .yaml file:

```
!obj:pylearn2.train.Train {
    "dataset": !obj:pylearn2.datasets.make_dataset.Classificator {}
 }
```

Comment: could you please show your import statements?

Comment: @nio I import throught .yaml file. You can see it at the bottom of the question: pylearn2.datasets.make_dataset.Classificator

Comment: What is inside your `__init__.py` in the `datasets` directory?

Comment: @SethMMorton nothing. It's empty, why?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing `__init__.py` file in your `pylearn2\` directory
[There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application) is some information about directory structure. [There](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) is official documentation for modules.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `__init__.py`, you need to import the modules inside the directory.  Otherwise you  can't import submodules in the way you describe.

`datasets/__init__.py`:

```
import hepatitis
import matlab_dataset
import make_dataset
```

If your `__init__.py` is empty, you could do an `import pylearn2.datasets`, and *then* access the submodules from in your code (i.e. `a = pylearn2.datasets.make_dataset.Classificator()`), but to actually do `import pylearn2.datasets.make_dataset` you need to import the submodules in the `__init__.py`.