# Python Setup.py

Tags: python, packaging, setup.py

So I am a neophile at python building and packaging.

I am confused as to whether my setup is viable, and whether there is a better way of structuring the code file-wise to enable better packaging.

In essence, I have:

```
/top_folder/
|___setup.py
|___file1.py
|___file2.py
|___lib/                        <--- (FOLDER)
    |_____ binary1
    |_____ libfile1.py
    |_____ libfile2.awk
    |_____ __init__.py
```

Is a setup.py file such as this the right way to go about things?

```
setup(
    name='myName',
    version='1.0a',
    #packages=['lib'],
    url='http://myUrl.co.uk',
    license='GPL2',
    author='myAuthorName',
    author_email='myAuthorEmail',
    description='myDescription',
    py_modules=['file1', 'file2']
)
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this [Open Sourcing a Python Project the Right Way](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/) post may help. It covers not only setup.py file, but almost all tools and concepts.

Answer (score 0):

**create a file to run this command:**

python.exe build.py py2exe

**Build.py should contain this (minus the notes):**

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
```

Note: Any modules/libraries you need to include (this one uses timer.py)
    MODULE_LIST = ["timer"]

Note: 'bundle_files': 1' and zipfile=None compiles every into one exe with no dependencies
console = script will make your exe run your python program as a script in the console. **PyFindReplaceThreaded.py** is the py file you want to build.

```
setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    console = [{'script': "PyFindReplaceThreaded.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```