# Import package "x" in module "x": prevent importing itself and import package instead

Tags: python-3.x, pythonpath, project-structure

I run into problems when using a project structure as suggested here: [What is the best project structure for a Python application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application).

Imagine a project layout like this:

```
Project/
|-- bin/
|   |-- project.py
|
|-- project/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- foo.py
```

In *bin/project.py* I want to import from package *project*.

```
#project.py
from project import foo
```

Since sys.path[0] is always *Project/bin* when running *bin/project.py*, it tries to import the module *bin/project.py* (itself) resulting in an attribute error. Is there a way to use this project layout without playing around with sys.path in the module *bin/project.py*? I basically would need a "importpackage" statement, that ignores modules with same name.

Since the project structure is suggested, I'm wondering why no one else has this kind of problems...

Comment: Don't run it from that directory?

Comment: As I said, I don't want to change the project structure, since it seems to be the "standard" layout

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
import imp
module_name = imp.load_source('project','../project')
```

module_name would be the package.

EDIT:

For python 3.3+

```
import importlib.machinery

loader = importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader("project", "../project")
foo = loader.load_module("project")
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: I'm actually using python 3.3, the module imp in python 3.3 has no method load_source

Comment: Added 3.3+ equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I hoped there is some "importpackage" statement, that explicitly only loads packages and skips single file modules to avoid importing itself. The way you do it might be a solution (even if I get some weird OS permission errors), but I wanted to avoid the use of relative paths. I see not much benefit in using the example above instead of "sys.path.append(sys.path.pop(0))".