# Project directory structure for a multi-language application

Tags: java, python, naming, directory-structure, project-structure

I recently started work on an application that involves both Python and Java components independent of each other. What is the best way to structure the folder hierarchy for the project, in particular the source files?

Right now the structure looks like this:

```
/src
 -- java packages here
/test
 -- jUnit test packages here
/deployment
 -- Ant scripts here
/bin
/lib
/etc
.gitignore
```

A possible solution would be to have `src/java` and `src/python` (as in, subdirectories under the `src` folder).
Another solution would be to have two separate directories in the project for instance `src_java` and `src_python`.
 anyone worked on a project like this? Is there a *de facto* convention that should be used?

I've read the answers to this question [What is the best project structure for a Python application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application) but the 6th point wasn't discussed much regarding the non-Python sources.

Answer (score 4):

In Gradle projects, it is [recommended](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html) to structure the folders like this:

```
src
  main
    java
    python
  test
    java
    python
build
libs
...
.gitignore
README.md
```

Maven [recommends](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) a similar structure.

Python has different [recommendations](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/), but since the Java build tools usually are more sophisticated (due to requiring compilation and output directories for that), I'd go with the Gradle or Maven structure.

Comment: Where is this practice common?  Can you provide any documentation (best practices guidelines, style guides, etc.) showing that this folder structure is widely recommended?

Comment: Claiming it's a common practice without providing any reference is basically hand waving. A Google search doesn't turn up any reputable source for this question.

Comment: I added some links and more explanation.