# PYTHON: nosetests import file path with multiple modules/files

Tags: python, unit-testing, import, nose

I'm currently working through [LearnPythonTheHardWay](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex48.html) and have reached [Exercise 48](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex48.html) which details **Nosetests**. I am able to perform a unit testing as long as all of the code is in a single python.py file. However if I include other files as part of a program, i.e. use **import** and then attempt to **nosetest** such a project I am getting an error, as follows:

> ======================================================================
>
> ### ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named 'temp')
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nose/failure.py", line 39, in runTest
>       raise self.exc_val.with_traceback(self.tb)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 414, in loadTestsFromName        ## ##
>       addr.filename, addr.module)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
>       return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
>       mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 235, in load_module
>       return load_source(name, filename, file)
>     File "/usr/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
>       module = methods.load()
>     File "", line 1220, in load
>     File "", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
>     File "", line 1129, in _exec
>     File "", line 1471, in exec_module
>     File "", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
>     File "/home/user/LEARNPYTHONTHEHARDWAY/ex48/tests/scanner_tests.py", line 6, in 
>       from ex48.scanner  import lexicon
>     File "/home/user/LEARNPYTHONTHEHARDWAY/ex48/ex48/scanner.py", line 6, in 
>       import temp
>   ImportError: No module named 'temp'

---

> Ran 1 test in 0.028s
>
> FAILED (errors=1)

The structure of my project directories are as follows:

```
ex48/
  ex48/
     scanner.py
     temp.py
  __pycache__/
  tests/
     __init__.py
    scanner_tests.py
```

Screenshot of my directory::

[image]

Screen shot of files themselves::

[image]

[image]

[image]
My **scanner_tests.py** file is as follows:

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex48.scanner import lexicon
from ex48 import temp

def test_directions():
    assert_equal(lexicon.scan("north"),[('direction','north')])
        result = lexicon.scan("north south east")
        assert_equal(result, [('direction', 'north'),
                          ('direction', 'south'),
                          ('direction', 'east')])
```

My **scanner.py** file is as follows:

```
   import temp

   class lexicon:
       def scan(val):
          if(val == "north"):
              return [('direction', 'north')]
          else:
              return [('direction', 'north'),
                      ('direction', 'south'),
                      ('direction', 'east')]

    runner = temp.temp("hello")
```

And finally my **temp.py** file is as follows:

```
   class temp(object):
       def __init__(self,name):
           self.name = name
       def run(self):
           print "Your name is; %s" % self.name     
    runner.run()
```

My question is how to overcome the **ImportError: No Module named 'temp'** because it seems as if I have imported the **temp.py** file in both the scanner.py file and the **scanner_tests.py** file but nose does not seem to be able to import it when it runs. *Nosetests* works fine when its just the single **scanner.py** file but not when importing. Is there a special syntax for importing into a unit test for nose? The script also works fine when run and imports properly at the command line.

*Note: I'm running python off a limited account off an online server so some admin privileges are not available.

**Note below are entirely different screenshots from another project with the exact same error:

Directory Layout:
[image]

Game.py:

[image]

Otherpy.py - the imported file:

[image]

the Nose test script file:

[image]

And finally the nosetests importerror:

[image]

Comment: Looking over your file layout, you are missing an `__init__.py` in your ex48 folder where settings and temp.py are. Can you ensure that you have the appropriate `__init__.py`'s in place and try again?

Comment: Added thanks-- but still getting same result :/

Comment: Where are you running nose from? inside the `ex48` directory?

Comment: Yes, the top ex48 directory inside which is the ex48/ and tests/

Comment: Where exactly are your `__init__.py` files?

Comment: ex48/ex48/__init__.py

Comment: add screenshot of directory listing

Comment: The first screen shot you are importing temp twice. What are you doing there? That should not be happening. Import one way and use that one.

Comment: And for the first screenshot, which file is that?

Comment: That is scanner.py

Comment: Look at your first screen shot...you have `from temp import temp` then below you have `import temp`. Remove `import temp`.

Comment: I removed that. I attached some more screenshots of an entirely different project, created from scratch which gives the same error. This has to be an issue with the path that nosetests is searching for when it does its imports but I've yet to see a workaround

Comment: You have the *exact* same exception when you removed `import temp` from the `scanner.py` file? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes same, same error also across projects.

Comment: What do you mean `across projects`? Also, if you removed `import temp`, then you should be getting a different exception because that line should no longer exist in your code.

Comment: Across projects ==  I started from scratch with a new project/directory, created simple .py files and tried to run a nosetests on these files and got the same importerror. I refer to them as the same exception because, while the line numbers may change, the same error results, that being: ImportError: No module named 'whatever' .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107808/discussion-between-idjaw-and-jeeves).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I have found is to post the following to the top of the main file:

```
try: 
     # This handles imports when running .py files from inside app directory
     from file_to_import.py import class_instance
except:
     # This handles imports when running nosetests from top-level (above app) 
     # directory
     from directory_containing_app_files.file_to_import import class_instance
```

I am supremely interested in an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Everything needs to be with respect to your execution point. You are running your nose command from the root of `ex48`, therefore all your imports need to be with respect to that location.

Therefore, in `game.py` you should be importing with respect to `ex48`. Therefore:

```
from ex48.otherpy import House
```

The same logic should be applied to your example referencing the `temp` folder.

```
from ex48.temp import temp
```