# Creating a Python Project using Atom

Tags: python-3.x, atom-editor

I m trying to create a python project in Atom IDE. I downloaded and installed Atom and also some package like project_manager.

I am finding it extremely hard to get going.

My project would have a few python files in the code folder. Some data files in the data folder, etc.

How do I start this in Python. I goggled this as well but still finding it difficult.

P.S. I know how to create python files and run them using IDLE. Want to do my work in a more structured manner by creating a project and then being able to compile and run my files fast and easily.

Regards
Bonson

Comment: Do you know how to do it outside of the Atom IDE?

Comment: if you're asking about directory structure, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application might be a good place to start

Comment: Thanks maxymoo. The structure details will definitely help. However, I am currently stuck with trying to create and run a python project from within Atom as I understand that it is a good IDE and it will help me in the long run in the python project.

Comment: Hi Ignacio, Updated my question. I know how to create and run python files using IDLE. But want a better IDE as I am about to go into a proper project based on python.