# about Jean Paul Calderone file system structure

Tags: python-3.x, import

[For a Python3 project of my own](https://github.com/suizokukan/eupompos), I'm trying to follow the [file system structure described by Jean-Paul Calderone](http://as.ynchrono.us/2007/12/filesystem-structure-of-python-project_21.html) ([credits for the original document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application)) :

```
MyProject/
|-- bin/
|   |-- myproject
|
|-- myproject/
|   |-- test/
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- test_main.py
|   |   
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- main.py
|
|-- setup.py
|-- README
```

My project isn't mature but the tests are ok : a call to `nosetests` **run the different parts of the code as expected**.

So now, I'm trying to produce an executable, an "external entry point" to my code. I'm struggling with **the content of the executable (bin/myproject)**; I read in [Jean-Paul Calderone blog](http://as.ynchrono.us/2007/12/filesystem-structure-of-python-project_21.html) :

> Don't give them a .py extension, even if they are Python source
>   files. Don't put any code in them except an import of and call to a
>   main function defined somewhere else in your projects.

So, I tried to fill the executable with the following lines...

```
from ..myproject.main import main
main()
```

... but being in the `Project` directory and calling my program with `bin/myproject` raises an import error :

> SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

I can't go further : any idea to help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I got it :

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append( os.path.join("..", "myproject") )

from myproject.main import main
main()
```

: adding the right path to sys.path does the trick.

By the way, creating such an executable script isn't required by Pypi which can create an entry point of its own; see the following lines in [setup.py](https://github.com/suizokukan/eupompos/blob/master/setup.py) :

```
entry_points={
    # let's create an executable script named 'myproject' :
    'console_scripts': ['myproject=myproject.main:main',],
},
```

... But such an executable script is a very convenient way to try the project without installing it using pypi; such a script makes easy to launch the project "on the fly".