# Why do I get ImportError when running the tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I am using Python 3 to try and get a test file for sample application working yet it keeps throwing `ImportError: No module named 'calculate'`

My file structure is:

```
/calculate
  __init__.py
  calculate.py
  test/
    __init__.py
    calculate_test.py
```

I cannot figure out why this is the case, any help would be much appreciated.

The `__init__.py` files are empty.

**calculate.py** contains:

```
class Calculate(object):
    def add(self, x, y):
        return x + y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    calc = Calculate()
    result = calc.add(2, 2)
    print(result)
```

**calculate_test.py** contains:

```
import unittest
from calculate import Calculate

class TestCalculate(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.calc = Calculate()

    def test_add_method_returns_correct_result(self):
        self.assertEqual(4, self.calc.add(2,2))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I am running `python test/calculate_test.py` from the root `/calculate` folder and am getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/calculate_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from calculate import Calculate
ImportError: No module named 'calculate'
```

I have been fiddling around with different structures and cannot understand what the problem is.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142151/python-how-to-import-the-class-within-the-same-directory-or-sub-directory

Answer (score 0):

Your project's structure is the reason. The test script doesn't have the outer directory in the search path when you start it. Here are some ways to fix that

1. Move the test file into the same directory that contains the module it imports. That will require no changes in the test file.
2. Use this structure

   ```
   ./project/
       calculate_test.py
       calculate/
           __init__.py
           calculate.py
   ```

   This will require you to change the import signature in calculate_test.py to something like `from calculate import calculate`

Comment: I am now getting an error saying `name Calculate is not defined` when defining `self.calc = Calculate()` in the setup method.

Comment: calculate_test.py needs to access Calculate from calculate/calculate.py, so you need "from calculate.calculate import Calculate"

Comment: I think it's better practice to have the tests inside the packages hierarchy

Comment: @λuser what structure do you suggest? I would ideally like to have a tests folder to separate out the classes and test files

Comment: I'd suggest doing like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5998845 Having tests in a hierarchy allows sharing stuff between them, better organization, etc.