# Calling script in standard project directory structure (Python path for bin subdirectory)

Tags: python, setup.py

I am experimenting with putting my Python code into the standard directory structure used for deployment with `setup.py` and maybe PyPI. for a Python library called mylib it would be something like this:

```
mylibsrc/
  README.rst
  setup.py
  bin/
    some_script.py
  mylib/
    __init.py__
    foo.py
```

There's often also a `test/` subdirectory but I haven't tried writing unit tests yet. The recommendation to have scripts in a `bin/` subdirectory can be found in the [official Python packaging documentation](http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html).

Of course, the scripts start with code that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from mylib.foo import something
something("bar")
```

This works well when it eventually comes to deploying the script (e.g. to devpi) and then installing it with pip. But if I run the script directly from the source directory, as I would while developing new changes to the library/script, I get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'mylib'
```

This is true even if the current working directory is the root `mylibsrc/` and I ran the script by typing `./bin/some_script.py`. This is because Python starts searching for packages in the directory of the script being run (i.e. from `bin/`), not the current working directory.

What is a good, permament way to make it easy to run scripts while developing packages?

Here is a [relevant other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application) (especially comments to the first answer).

The solutions for this that I've found so far fall into three categories, but none of them are ideal:

1. Manually fix up your Python's module search path somehow before running your scripts.

   - You can manually add `mylibsrc` to my `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. This seems to be the most official (Pythonic?) solution, but means that every time I check out a project I have to remember to manually change my environment before I can run any code in it.
   - Add `.` to the start of my `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. As I understand it this could have some security problems. This would actually be my favoured trick if I was the only person to use my code, but I'm not, and I don't want to ask others to do this.
   - While looking at answers on the internet, for files in a `test/` directory I've seen recommendations that they all (indirectly) include a line of code `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))` (e.g. in [structuring your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application)). Yuck! This seems like a bearable hack for files that are only for testing, but not those that will be installed with the package.
   - Edit: I have since found an alternative, which turns out to be in this category: by running the scripts with Python's `-m` script, the search path starts in the working directory instead of the `bin/` directory. See my answer below for more details.
2. Install the package to a virtual environment before using it, using a setup.py (either running it directly or using pip).

   - This seems like overkill if I'm just testing a change that I'm not sure is even syntactically correct yet. Some of the projects I'm working on aren't even meant to be installed as packages but I want to use the same directory structure for everything, and this would mean writing a setup.py just so I could test them!
   - Edit: Two interesting variants of this are discussed in the answers below: the `setup.py develop` command in logc's answer and `pip install -e` in mine. They avoid having to re-"install" for every little edit, but you still need to create a `setup.py` for packages you never intend to fully install, and doesn't work very well with PyCharm (which has a menu entry to run the `develop` command but no easy way to run the scripts that it copies to the virtual environment).
3. Move the scripts to the project's root directory (i.e. in `mylibsrc/` instead of `mylibsrc/bin/`).

   - Yuck! This is a last resort <strike>but, unfortunately, this seems like the only feasible option at the moment</strike>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Run modules as scripts

Since I posted this question, I've learnt that you can run a module as if it were a script using Python's `-m` command-line switch (which I had thought only applied to packages).

So I think the best solution is this:

- Instead of writing wrapper scripts in a bin subdirectory, put the bulk of the logic in modules (as you should anyway), and put at the end of relevant modules `if __name__ == "__main__": main()`, as you would in a script.
- To run the scripts on the command line, call the modules directly like this: `python -m pkg_name.module_name`
- If you have a setup.py, as Alik said you can generate wrapper scripts at installation time so your users don't need to run them in this funny way.

PyCharm doesn't support running modules in this way (see [this request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-2784)). However, you can just run modules (and also scripts in bin) like normal because PyCharm automatically adds the project root to the PYTHONPATH, so import statements resolve without any further effort. There are a few gotchas for this though:

- The main problem the working directory will be incorrect, so opening data files won't work. Unfortunately there is no quick fix; the first time you run each script, you must then stop it and change its configured working directory (see [this link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205811019-default-working-directory)).
- If your package directory is not directly within the root project directory, you need to mark its parent directory as a source directory in the project structure settings page.
- Relative imports don't work i.e. you can do `from pkg_name.other_module import fn` but not `from .other_module import fn`. Relative imports are usually poor style anyway, but they're useful for unit tests.
- If a module has a circular dependency and you run it directly, it will end up being imported twice (once as `pkg_name.module_name` and once as `__main__`). But you shouldn't have circular dependencies anyway.

Bonus command line fun:

- If you still want to put some scripts in `bin/` you can call them with `python -m bin.scriptname` (but in Python 2 you'll need to put an `__init__.py` in the bin directory).
- You can even run the overall package, if it has a `__main__.py`, like this: `python -m pkg_name`

## Pip editable mode

There is an alternative for the command line, which is not as simple, but still worth knowing about:

- Use pip's editable mode, [documented here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs)
- To use it, make a setup.py, and use the following command to install the package into your virtual environment: `pip install -e .`
- Note the trailing dot, which refers to the current directory.
- This puts the scripts generated from your setup.py in your virtual environment's bin directory, and links to your package source code so you can edit and debug it without re-running pip.
- When you're done, you can run `pip uninstall pkg_name`
- This is similar to `setup.py`'s `develop` command, but uninstallation seems to work better.

Comment: I didn't get how this solution works, do you have an example of the final structure you should have to get the code to work in PyCharm and also respect the `bin` folder project structure?

Comment: @RobertoLeinardi For the project structure, I use the one I stated in the question. As I said in this answer, PyCharm should find packages by default because it adds the project directory to the `PYTHONPATH` by default (just right click on the script and choose "run" or "debug"). If your PyCharm project is a parent directory of the Python project (e.g. so you can see several different projects at once), you can go into the settings dialog box, and in "project structure" page, right click on the project directory and click "sources" to mark it as a sources root.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use `setuptools` in your `setup.py` script, and use the `entry_points` keyword, see the documentation of [Automatic Script Creation](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation).

In more detail: you create a `setup.py` that looks like this

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    # other arguments here...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'foo = my_package.some_module:main_func',
            'bar = other_module:some_func',
        ],
        'gui_scripts': [
            'baz = my_package_gui:start_func',
        ]
    }
)
```

then create other Python packages and modules underneath the directory where this `setup.py` exists, e.g. following the above example:

```
.
├── my_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── some_module.py
├── my_package_gui
│   └── __init__.py
├── other_module.py
└── setup.py
```

and then run

```
$ python setup.py install
```

or

```
$ python setup.py develop
```

Either way, new Python scripts (executable scripts without the `.py` suffix) are created for you that point to the entry points you have described in `setup.py`. Usually, they are at the Python interpreter's notion of "directory where executable binaries should be", which is usually on your PATH already. If you are using a virtual env, then `virtualenv` tricks the Python interpreter into thinking this directory is `bin/` under wherever you have defined that the virtualenv should be. Following the example above, in a virtualenv, running the previous commands should result in:

```
bin
├── bar
├── baz
└── foo
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. The stuff about `entry_points` is interesting but misses the whole point: I don't want to install a package just to try every tiny experimental change (actually it makes this worse!). But you mentioned in passing a nugget that is a real solution: the `setup.py develop` command. This would work both with `entry_points` and regular scripts. It's a pity that it requires you to create a `setup.py` even for packages that you never intend to properly install, and not easy to access from an IDE like PyCharm.