# How to import my own modules the elegant way?

Tags: python-3.x

I am struggling with a dummy question about importing classes from another sub-directory and I can’t find satisfying solution. Here is the context: I have a root folder, let’s call it project, that contains two sub folders, called app and test.

In app, I have my classes files, class1.py and so on. In test, I have test_class1.py to hold my unit test class. Seems to be some standard folder structure to me. How do I import class1 from test_class1.py? So far I append ‘../app’ to my sys.path but it looks so ugly to me! I tried `from ..app import class1` and so many other combinations unsuccessfully.

Second question: Are `__init__.py` still needed in python 3.6+?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1/ Regarding your first question, based on my own experience, I would structure the project as follow:

```
project/
  app/
   class1.py
   __init__.py
   ...
  test/
   context.py
   test_class1.py
   __init__.py
   ...
  setup.py
  ...
```

> Obviously, these test modules must import your packaged module to test
>   it. You can do this a few ways:
>
> - Expect the package to be installed in site-packages.
> - Use a simple (but explicit) path modification to resolve the package properly.
>
> I highly recommend the latter. Requiring a developer to run setup.py
>   develop to test an actively changing codebase also requires them to
>   have an isolated environment setup for each instance of the codebase.
>
> To give the individual tests import context, create a tests/context.py
>   file:

**context.py*** should bootstrap the testing context as follow:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

import app
from app import class1
...
```

Then in your test_class1.py file, I would import the tested Class as follow:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from .context import class1  # or from context.class1 import MyClass

class TestClass1(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.to_be_tested = class1.MyClass() # or MyClass()
```

2/ Regarding your second question about **__init__.py** file being needed or not in python 3.6+, I let you read the following existing answer:
[Is __init__.py not required for packages in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3)

**Possible Interesting references**:

- https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/#structure-of-the-repository
- https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/#test-suite
- [Running unittest with typical test directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896918/running-unittest-with-typical-test-directory-structure)
- [What is the best project structure for a Python application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application)
- https://packaging.python.org/

Answer (score 1):

```
from app import class1
```

you do not need `__init__.py` for create packages from 3.3+

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following in `test_class1.py`

```
import os
import sys
import unittest

parent_dir = "/".join(sys.path[0].split("/")[:-1])    # On Linux
parent_dir = "\\".join(sys.path[0].split("\\")[:-1])  # On Windows

sys.path.append(parent_dir)

from app import class1

## bla bla
```

And when you call `test_class1.py` you need to do the following:

```
python -m test.test_class1
```