# Unable to import the file in python

Tags: python, import, python-import

i have the following directory structure

```
dira/
    __init__.py
    a.py
    b.py
    dirc/
        __init__.py
        c.py
```

I need to import `b.py` in `c.py` and import `c.py` in `a.py`

a.py :-

```
from dirc.c import *
```

This is not working it is giving the error:-

```
Unable to import 'dirc.c  'pylint(import-error)'
```

c.py :-

```
from dira.b import *
```

This is giving the error:-

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dira'
```

I don't know why the imports not working, what's the issue?
i tried the suggested answer:-

c.py:-

```
from ..b import *
```

error:-

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't import my own modules in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383014/cant-import-my-own-modules-in-python)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51592182/how-to-import-my-own-modules-the-elegant-way) also helps