# I am having difficulty importing a list from another file in Python

Tags: python, list, import

I am a beginner to Python, and I am having trouble importing a list into my other Python file. I have two files. One is `article_analyzer.py` and the other is `keywords.py`. Both are in the same directory. I have tried importing a list called `keywords_list` from `keywords.py`. But it is not working. I have tried typing `import keywords` and then printing `print(keywords_list)`, but this just results in this error: `NameError: name 'keywords_list' is not defined`. I have also tried `from keywords import *` but it results in the same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't import my own modules in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383014/cant-import-my-own-modules-in-python)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51592182/how-to-import-my-own-modules-the-elegant-way) also helps

Comment: `import keywords;print(keywords.keywords_list)` may be what you want

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what I did, but I played around with the `keywords.py` file and it appears to be working now.

Answer (score -1):

you can't import local variable from other file, you can import function, class or global variable.

for example

```py
# keywords.py

def keywords_list:
  return ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

```py
# article_analyzer.py

import keywords

keywords_list = keywords.keywords_list()
print(keywords_list)
# [a, b, c]
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. It did not work when I tried it. I tried to define a different function in the  `keywords.py` folder and I still got the same error.