# Python virtualenv needs to be created in the same place with the project it belongs to?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, project

Recently I start a project based on Flask/Python. Right now I have set the environment - but I never create a project step by step in python, I have only experienced little scripts and small apps when I learn the programming language.

I have install and set all the dependencies in the same folder as you can see here:

[image]

In 'env' - I have create the virtual environment.

In 'TheSocial' - is and it will be the application itself.

**My questions are**:

1) If this 'env' will be moved or it wasn't created inside 'project_py', my application from 'TheSocial' can still run inside the virutalenv, or not ?

2) Are there any standards that you need to respect when you created any project structure ?

I have also seen an already answered [StackOverFlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application) , but I want to find out answers for *question 1)*

*This questions are addressed in scope to understand how real projects are structured and design from scratch.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Creating virtualenv changes your sytem's $PATH:

```
 $ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Users/wgonczaronek/bin:/usr/local/sbin
 $ source venv/bin/activate
 $ echo $PATH
/Users/wgonczaronek/Projects/django & flask security/CSP/csp-flask/venv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Users/wgonczaronek/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

Inside `activate` there are following lines responsible for this:

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/Users/wgonczaronek/Projects/django & flask security/CSP/csp-flask/venv"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
```

This means that when you move your env this will no longer be valid.

2) Just be consistent. In my project I like to "encapsulate" git repository in a directory of the same name where I keep my virtual env and other things (I have a special file FFF.txt which stands for Frequently Forgotten Features where I save all project related info for personal use :D). This allows me to clean after project in one command when I want to get rid of it and I am not bothered with naming conventions of my environment - I do not have to edit `.gitignore`. Some people like to use [virtual env wrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) which  keep all virtual env outside project though. Just experiment and find out what suits you best.