# Python import error solution. (Need a better approach)

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

My Dir structure is like this

```
├── server.py
└── Utils
    ├── A.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── B.py
```

Inside server.py, one import is there

```
from Utils.B import SomeClass
```

Inside B.py there's also one import

```
from .A import SomeClass
```

While running server.py, it's running fine. But while running B.py inside Utils, it's throwing error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.A'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Then removing the dot and then running, B.py is working fine but server.py is throwing error.
Can there be any solution which will run both fine?

Answer (score 1):

I would try staying away from relative imports (the ones with a leading `.`).

A generally good file structure looks like this:

```
Project
├── setup.py
├── README.md
└── project
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── server.py
    └── Utils
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── A.py
        └── B.py
```

The main takeaways here are:

- There's a main folder called `Project` holding all the files.
- Directly inside that one we put all meta-files such as `setup.py` and `README.md` and all that jazz. We don't put any code here because we don't want this folder to be seen as a package (no dunder init file).
- We create a second folder, having the same name but with lower case (`project`), this is the main `python package` as we put a dunder init file in here. This is the base for all our imports.
- Then with every import we define the full path like this: `from project.Utils.A import SomeClass`.
- If you want that class to be easily imported from your package then you can write `from project.Utils.A import SomeClass` inside the first dunder init file, after which you can do `from project import SomeClass` whenever you need it.

This answer is also really good and relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3419951/3936044

Comment: I used the file structure. Now it's showing:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 1, in <module>
    from demo.utils.b import B
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'demo'

Comment: In your example you had capitalized `Utils` and `B.py`, if it's not that then I cannot really help you without you showing your exact structure and code, you'll have to ask another question in that case

Comment: It's the same structure. I just changed some_function to B and utils to Utils. If this is the case of error, I'll change it