# Why can't Python find the files I'm importing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Recently I started working on a new Python project, and I thought I might structure it properly, not throw all the code in one directory like I usually do. Using [this tutorial](https://dev.to/codemouse92/dead-simple-python-project-structure-and-imports-38c6#packages-and-modules) I created a folder structure like this for my project:

```
myappholder/
myappholder/README.md
myappholder/LICENSE.txt
myappholder/.gitignore
myappholder/myapp/
myappholder/myapp/__init__.py (empty file)
myappholder/myapp/main.py
myappholder/myapp/config.py
myappholder/myapp/subdir
myappholder/myapp/subdir/__init__.py (empty file)
myappholder/myapp/subdir/helper.py
```

Contents of `main.py`:

```py
from myapp.subdir.helper import sayHello
```

Contents of `subdir/helper.py`:

```py
from myapp.config import SOME_CONST

def sayHello():
    print(SOME_CONST)
```

Contents of `config.py`:

```py
SOME_CONST = 'Hello world'
```

When running `python main.py` (from `myappholder/myapp`), I get this error (trace removed for brevity): `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myapp`. When running `python -m main` (from `myappholder/myapp`) I get the same error.

I know it's probably a really simple thing that I'm doing wrong but a few hours of googling did nothing to fix the problem. I'm not sure if the problem is with how I'm setting up the project or how I'm running it but any help will be appreciated.

Details:

- I'm running Python 3.8 on Windows
- I'm trying to create a GUI application, not a library

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best project structure for a Python application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application)

Comment: @sahasrara62 no, not really. In any case, aahnik's answer solved my problem.

Comment: this is for reference, as the solution is present in one of the solutions there, the issue is at what directory level in the project you are running project.

Comment: @sahasrara62 ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be in your **root folder** (myappholder) to run everything.

Your directory structure is like this: (when you are inside myappholder)

Write your directory structure in a better fashion, like this:

```sh
.
├── myapp
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── subdir
│       ├── helper.py
│       └── __init__.py
└── README.md
```

### long and full solution

Understand how python imports work. You seem not to know that in detail.

Read this detailed and wonderful article: https://realpython.com/python-import/

concepts that you need to learn:

- [Absolute and Relative Imports](https://realpython.com/python-import/#absolute-and-relative-imports)
- [Python’s Import Path](https://realpython.com/python-import/#pythons-import-path)
- [Official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) of how python imports internally work

---

### quick solution for testing you application

Open your terminal and run `python` (from your project's root directory)

now in this interactive shell, import `myapp` and call the function you need to run.

---

### exposing a cli

If you need to expose a CLI , you may package your application, and using [`poetry`](https://python-poetry.org/) or [setuptools](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) is great.

You could define a command line interface.

For example,if you are using poetry, you can put this in your pyproject.toml

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
samplepy = 'samplepy:cli'
```

now, running, `samplepy` from the terminal will execute, the `cli` function of the `samplepy` package.

Comment: I've marked this as accepted because it contains more information than the other two. However, they are both still valid answers.

Answer (score 1):

So you're running from `myappholder/myapp`? Either run from `myappfolder` or remove the first level of hierarchy (`myapp` in `from myapp.X.X`).

Answer (score 1):

in `myappholder` create a another `main_app.py` file, in this file call the function/module from `myapp/main.py` which run the project.

then run the `main_app.py` script, it will work