# Python git project-structure convention?

Tags: python, conventions

Is there a convention(or even a PEP) on how to structure a python project for example on GitHub? More specifically python-specific files(I know about the README.md, licence, .gitignore-files).

I've googled the whole morning and found different approaches. Most of them use:

- a requirements.txt file
- a setup.py file

One used a makefile some other added a .travis.yml for travis and so on... .
And they split their project directories in different folders like data and APP.

**My Questions:**

1. What files should I include in a python-project? What files would be nice to have?
2. Is there a convention how I should arrange different folders like data and APP or is it up to me how I want to split, name and organize the different parts of my program?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Does [this](https://realpython.com/python-application-layouts/) take from Real Python help?

Comment: Does "Github" really matter? It's just a project. Shouldn't matter where it is stored... My recommendation would be to start with `poetry` projects or `cookiecutter` templates. Obviously [packaging matters](https://packaging.python.org/), but CI/CD scripts are highly dependent on what you use

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best project structure for a Python application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely dependent on what you are building. The [article](https://realpython.com/python-application-layouts/) I linked in my comment breaks out different layouts like so:

CLI Layouts:

- One-Off Script
- Installable Single Package
- Application with Internal Packages

Web App Layouts:

- Django
- Flask

While link only answers are discouraged here, I think its counter productive to rehash the whole article but the "Installable Single Package" layout has worked for me and looks like this (borrowed from the same article):

```
helloworld/
│
├── helloworld/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── helloworld.py
│   └── helpers.py
│
├── tests/
│   ├── helloworld_tests.py
│   └── helpers_tests.py
│
├── .gitignore
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

*NOTE:* If you have a data directory, I would put it at the same level as `tests`

Comment: Thanks the article on realpython really helped(but took me some time to read)!
I really like that it takes other examples and provides a good solid overview.

To your NOTE, if the data is only for testing I would put it also at the same level as tests.

But if I should have data, that is changeable and still needs to be present after a reboot I should save it in a file under a data directory?

Comment: @123 I don't have much a strong opinion here but under `Application with Internal Packages` Real Python states of the data directory:
**_Having this directory is helpful for testing. It’s a central location for any files that your  application will ingest or produce. Depending on how you deploy your application, 
you can keep “production-level” inputs and outputs pointed to this directory, or only use it for internal testing._**
I take that to be data should always have its own directory