# No Module named utils.utils , utils is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

I have a Project where there is a python(.py) file inside a Directory say A, under the folder A , I have a file having the code:

```
from utils.utils import csv_file_transform
```

where utils is a sibling directory to A

```
 /A
  file.py

 /utils
    __init__.py
    utils.py
```

but, I am getting a error No Module named utils.utils, utils is not a package
I tried adding the path using sys, but its still giving the same error

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Users/Sri/Documents/newmod/folder/utils')
```

The code is working fine in ubuntu but not in windows, I am using a windows system

Comment: yes there is a empty __init__.py

Answer (score 0):

as much as I don't support link only / reference only answers I reckon that your question is answered best by referencing the existing discussions and providing broader context on Python importing mechanism.

## Your Requirements

- *Are you actually working on creating on Python module?* If this is the case, it would be good if you could establish a rigorous structure for your module and follow those guidelines.
- Consider [the following article](https://dev.to/codemouse92/dead-simple-python-project-structure-and-imports-38c6) by Jason C. McDonald on strutting a hypothetical module `omission` in Python. Given the following structure:

  ```
     omission-git
     ├── LICENSE.md
     ├── omission
     │   ├── app.py
     │   ├── common
     │   │   ├── classproperty.py
     │   │   ├── constants.py
     │   │   ├── game_enums.py
     │   │   └── __init__.py
     │   ├── data
     │   │   ├── data_loader.py
     │   │   ├── game_round_settings.py
     │   │   ├── __init__.py
     │   │   ├── scoreboard.py
     │   │   └── settings.py
     │   ├── game
     │   │   ├── content_loader.py
     │   │   ├── game_item.py
     │   │   ├── game_round.py
     │   │   ├── __init__.py
     │   │   └── timer.py
     │   ├── __init__.py
     │   ├── __main__.py
     │   ├── resources
     │   └── tests
     │       ├── __init__.py
     │       ├── test_game_item.py
     │       ├── test_game_round_settings.py
     │       ├── test_scoreboard.py
     │       ├── test_settings.py
     │       ├── test_test.py
     │       └── test_timer.py
     ├── pylintrc
     ├── README.md
     └── .gitignore
  ```

  Jason would import the modules in a following manner `from omission.common.game_enums import GameMode`.

## Relative Imports

[@am5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4521562/am5) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49375740/1655567) adding

```
import os, sys; sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

to your `__init__.py` files. If you study the [related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16981921/1655567) you will observer that views on modifying `sys.path` are diverse. Some may argue that failed imports and errors like:

> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

are actually indication of [code smell](https://iq-inc.com/importerror-attempted-relative-import/). As a solution, which I hope you won't find patronising, I would suggest that you solve your importing challenge by:

a) Deciding on your requirements on how "deep" you want to go into modular architecture.
b) Adopting a corresponding recommended architecture with rigorous approach to module structure
c) Refraining from hard-coding any path via `sys.path`. Appending relative paths, as outlined above, is not a flawless solution but has some merits and may be worth considering.

## Other worthy discussions/artefacts

- [Best structure for the Python project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/193161/1655567)
- Sample project by PyPa ([GitHub](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject))
- [Importing files from different folders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4383571/1655567)