# What is the best way to combine conda with standard python packaging tools (e.g. requirements.txt or pyproject.toml files)?

Tags: python, pip, conda, pyproject.toml

I work in scientific computing, and I am effectively forced to use conda to install certain other maintained packages to do my job. If I want to work on my own package, I need a way for it to play nice with both the conda dependency solver and pip. I would want to simply `conda install` the local package and use the conda dependency solver so that its compatible with the other software. However, I would also want to be able to otherwise `pip install` the package and/or upload it to PYPI.

Is there a way to develop a standardized python package (using, e.g., `pyproject.toml` and/or `requirements.txt` files) compatible with a conda environment? I have searched and haven't found a clear prescription on how to do so.

For conda, one could also locally specify the required dependencies  [in a `*.yml` file](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file), but this option is not compatible with installation via pip. One would have to maintain dependencies in *both* a `*.yml` file as well as a `requirements.txt` file. This duplication results in manual maintenance and is error-prone.

Note that the [conda develop](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/main/resources/commands/conda-develop.html) command is officially supported by anaconda and on the surface looks like it could be used to address this problem; however, it is  [effectively deprecated](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/4251) and as of this writing doesn't seem to be supported on python 3.11.

Answer (score 10):

I have cobbled together a method that forgoes the `*.yml` file altogether. I keep all of the dependencies in a `requirements.txt` file (and all dev requirements in  `requirements-dev.txt`) and use conda (or better yet [mamba](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge)) to install them. Finally, I use pip to install the package itself.

Below is an example of the file structure for the project (inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193161/what-is-the-best-project-structure-for-a-python-application)):

```
Project/
|-- src/
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- main.py
|
|-- pyproject.toml
|-- requirements.txt
|-- requirements-dev.txt
```

Among the other metadata in `pyproject.toml`, we must specify that we want to dynamically read the requirements from `requirements.txt`, as well as any other optional dependencies we might want (e.g., `requirements-dev.txt`):

**pyproject.toml**

```
[project]
name = "myproject"
...
dynamic = ["dependencies", "optional-dependencies"]

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
dependencies = { file = ["requirements.txt"] }

[tool.setuptools.dynamic.optional-dependencies]
dev = { file = ["requirements-dev.txt"] }
```

**Installation with pip**

The current structure works perfectly with pip, including either an editable install and/or optional dependencies:

```
# local installation of the package:
pip install .

# editable install:
pip install -e .

# editable install with optional dependencies:
pip install -e `.[dev]`
```

**Installation with conda**

Things are not as straightforward when using conda. When creating an environment from scratch:

```
conda create -n ENVNAME "python>=3.11" --file requirements.txt
```

If adding to an established environment, use `update`:

```
conda update --name ENVNAME --file requirements.txt
```

If installing a second set of dependencies (say, dev dependencies stored in `requirements-dev.txt`), you likely don't want them to affect the original dependencies (Otherwise, you would be testing a slightly different package, for example). You can freeze them using `freeze-installed`:

```
conda update --name ENVNAME --freeze-installed --file requirements-dev.txt
```

Finally, with all of the dependencies being taken care of by conda, the package can be installed to the environment using `pip`.

```
pip install --no-build-isolation --no-deps .
```

The `--no-deps` and `--build-isolation` flags [are necessary](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/4251#issuecomment-1053460542) to keep pip from meddling with the environment being maintained by conda.

Comment: Can you give an example of what your requirements.txt would look like in this example?